# Stop Akka actor while running

Tags: java, akka

I'm starting to use Akka with Java.

1. If I send a message to an actor that starts a cpu-bound process, is it possible to stop this actor while he is processing that message or I have to wait that it ends it? (I've seen that stop() anf kill first wait the end).
2. How can I run actors in parallel? Is it possible to see 2 actors like 2 parallel threads and kill one of those when I want?

Comment: [This discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/ly9g9CHvMmg) led to [this issue](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/455-add-interrupted-as-actor-status-%28running%29#/activity/ticket:) in 2010 which Viktor Klang closed as invalid 2011. It looks like it would have added an interrupt flag on Actor that you could check similar to `Thread.interrupted()`. It doesn't look like such a feature ever made it in. I think you may need to invent your own way of breaking your CPU work into chunks and run one chunk per message received.

Comment: so you're saying that is impossible to delete the actor thread, is only possible to divide the entire work in chunks and work one by one? Is it possible to delete an actor from the actorSystem also if it'is in a running state?

Comment: Essentially, yes. This is the nature of the JVM; threads cannot be forcefully halted. There is nothing Akka could do to change that.

Comment: And is there possibility to delete an actor from the actorSystem whenever I want?

Comment: Such that it's still running after it's removed? I doubt it.

Comment: No it's not still running. Suppose I have an actor with another actor as his child. I send a message from parent to the child and while child is running the message, the parent decide to delete the child. So after deleting the child no longer exists.

Comment: because my problem is that I have a child actor who,when a particular message occours from parent, starts a loop. This loop must be interrupted by parent in certain situations. The problem is that if the cpu-bound loop starts it can't never be interrupted by the parent also if I send a stop message.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't stop processing current message because it can lead to inconsistent state of your application. All you can do is not to process all the next messages by calling `stop(actorRef)` method.
2. Actors ARE parallel, this is their main feature. You just create one actor, then another, send messages to them and they both run in parallel.